# unable to load csv file from GCS into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am unable to load 500mb csv file from google cloud storage to big query but i got this error

```
Errors:
Too many errors encountered. (error code: invalid)
Job ID  xxxx-xxxx-xxxx:bquijob_59e9ec3a_155fe16096e
Start Time  Jul 18, 2016, 6:28:27 PM
End Time    Jul 18, 2016, 6:28:28 PM
Destination Table   xxxx-xxxx-xxxx:DEV.VIS24_2014_TO_2017
Write Preference    Write if empty
Source Format   CSV
Delimiter   ,
Skip Leading Rows   1
Source URI  gs://xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-dev/VIS24 2014 to 2017.csv.gz
```

I have gzipped 500mb csv file to csv.gz to upload to GCS.Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal details for your job show that there was an error reading the row #1 of your CSV file.  You'll need to investigate further, but it could be that you have a header row that doesn't conform to the schema of the rest of the file, so we're trying to parse a string in the header as an integer or boolean or something like that.  You can set the `skipLeadingRows` property to skip such a row.

Other than that, I'd check that the first row of your data matches the schema you're attempting to import with.

---

Also, the error message you received is unfortunately very unhelpful, so I've filed a bug internally to make the error you received in this case more helpful.

Comment: i have already selected Header rows to skip option as 1 because i am uploading file in bq browser tool.....any other suggestion to solve this error??

Comment: Ah, if you're already skipping a header row, then you might need to check the second row of your file.  Does the data in that row match the schema you provided on the job (e.g. right number of fields)?